# MySQL query conjunction acting abnormally

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm having a problem with a query.  I query from one table using the following process (using php PDO and MySQL):

Build the query string $sql:

```
SELECT *  
FROM  `user`  
WHERE (`username`=:username OR  `email`=:username) 
      AND  `password`=:password AND  `valid`='1';
```

And using this array $params:

```
Params
(
    [:password] => 18155dbf12503d726883784d1d9755f8d3382ba7
    [:username] => fakeEmail@fakeEmail.com
)
```

Call this function:

```
$results_array = $database->QueryForObject($sql, $params);

public function QueryForObject($query, $binds)
{
     $stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);

     foreach($binds as $bindKey => &$key)
     {
        $stmt->bindParam($bindKey, $key, PDO::PARAM_STR);
     }

     return $this->RunObjectQuery($stmt, NULL , "stdClass");
}
```

**My problem is that the username can be incomplete or even missing, and all it uses to find the user is the password...** I'm pretty sure it shouldn't do that, but I can't figure out why.

As a side note, here is the description of my table:

```
Field            , Type                                           , Null  ,Key  ,Default , Extra
id               , int(10) unsigned                               , NO    ,PRI  ,NULL     auto_increment 
username         , varchar(30)                                    , NO    ,UNI  ,NULL                    
email            , varchar(50)                                    , NO    ,     ,NULL                    
password         , varchar(100)                                   , NO    ,     ,NULL                    
first_name       , varchar(30)                                    , NO    ,     ,NULL                    
last_name        , varchar(30)                                    , NO    ,     ,NULL                    
rights           , enum('normal','medium','high','admin','super') , NO    ,     ,NULL                    
last_loggedin    , timestamp                                      , YES   ,     ,NULL                    
status           , enum('current','expired','temporary')          , NO    ,     ,NULL                    
valid            , tinyint(1)                                     , NO    ,     ,NULL                    
other_comments   , varchar(500)                                   , YES   ,     ,NULL                    
gender           , enum('male','female')                          , YES   ,     ,NULL                    
company_position , varchar(50)                                   ,  YES  ,     , NULL
```

Any suggestions are welcomed!!

Comment: Do you have rows with a blank email address?

Comment: Your not passing an email address so any empty email address records will be returned

Comment: The "username" can be either an actual username or an email, so the redundant :username, was on purpose.  It represents whatever the user uses to fill in the username input field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a definitive answer, but I believe I recall a bug with PDO and named bind parameters, with the same named bind parameter appearing more than once. (When we looked into it, it looked as the named arguments were being translated into positional arguments, and the bind_param was only setting one of the arguments.

As a workaround, we ensured that the named parameter appeared only once in the statement.

In your case, you might try (as a test) modifying the SQL so that it has only two named bind parameters, e.g.

```
SELECT *  
  FROM  `user`  
 WHERE :username IN (`username`,`email`)
   AND  `password`=:password AND `valid`='1';
```

Another alternative is to create a third named argument, and provide a separate bind value for the third parameter.

This isn't a definitive answer, just a suggestion of an approach that may allow you to  debug this issue.

(In our case, we went with the workaround, each named argument in the SQL statement was unique, and we provided a separate bind for each parameter.)

Comment: Hmm, both were good ideas! They don't seem to address the issue yet, but I'll keep experimenting. Thanks for your suggestions!  **EDIT** Nevermind!! I left a redundant `print_r(); exit;` statment in while I was adding your suggested changes. I took it out and your suggestions worked!